# How to get useful information about failed selenium test

Tags: selenium, web, element

I am wondering how I can get more useful information about a web element in Selenium test. Ex:

> Unable to locate element: at location {xpath: '//[@id = 'userId']}

This is not really helpful. I am thinking about creating a keyword for the element in my page object. So I can say

> Unable to locate the element 'currentUser' at this location.

Or how can I add all sorts of additional information If I wanna wrap an element? For example: "what kind of element it is and what page object it was in there".

Comment: Go with listeners

Comment: Look at the stack trace. This will tell you which page model you were in, as well as which field. You don't need this information. Can you include the stack trace as well?

Comment: Also, which programming language are you using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am using Java. In stack trace, it doesn't say what the element is. It only shows the strategy that was used for searching an element. If it says the element is not found at location css: [class='np-tmg']... I still need to spend time to understand what it is looking for. I want to make it more explicit. In this case, when the test fails, it will say: cannot find 'submitButton' for example.

Comment: Please post the stack trace anyhow. There might be something in it that you are missing, that we might spot.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I know how to debug, I don't have any problems with that. I just want to make some improvements. So in the future, I won't spend time and can see in the stack trace the name of the element which cannot be found.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I raised this question after I watched youtube video https://youtu.be/oeWfQQObsxI. On 42min the speaker is telling a good approach, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code that you have tried. We won't watch the YouTube video and then do the work for you.